# Is there a way to add a flip animation when I tap on my text?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Im trying to make a flash cards program and I can't seem to figure out how to make a flip animation to reveal the corresponding answer. Here is my code:

```
Text( "\(text)" + " \(X)" + " \(text1)")
    .frame(width: 120, height: 300, alignment: .center)
    .onTapGesture {
        if selection == "Multiply" { text = num1 * num2 clear() }
        if selection == "Addition" { text = num1 + num2 clear() }
        if selection == "Subtraction" { text = num1 - num2 clear() }
        if selection == "Division" { divAnswer = Double(num1 / num2) text = num1 / num2 clear() }
    }
```

(im very new to swifui)

Comment: Does this tutorial help to understand how the flip animation can be achieved: https://betterprogramming.pub/card-flip-animation-in-swiftui-45d8b8210a00

Answer (score 0):

Based on the tutorial from the link in the comment, I set up the following. It created just one card with one exercise, but it shows how it could work. You would have to adjust it to your needs:

```
//
//  CardFlip.swift
//  CardFlip
//
//  Created by Sebastian Fox on 26.08.22.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    // For testing, you can setup your exercise here
    @State var task: Task = Task(operator1: 5, operator2: 10, operation: .addition)
    
    //MARK: Variables
    @State var backDegree = 0.0
    @State var frontDegree = -90.0
    @State var isFlipped = false
    
    let width : CGFloat = 200
    let height : CGFloat = 250
    let durationAndDelay : CGFloat = 0.3
    
    //MARK: Flip Card Function
    func flipCard () {
        isFlipped = !isFlipped
        if isFlipped {
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: durationAndDelay)) {
                backDegree = 90
            }
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: durationAndDelay).delay(durationAndDelay)){
                frontDegree = 0
            }
        } else {
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: durationAndDelay)) {
                frontDegree = -90
            }
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: durationAndDelay).delay(durationAndDelay)){
                backDegree = 0
            }
        }
    }
    //MARK: View Body
    var body: some View {
    
        ZStack {
            CardBack(width: width, height: height, degree: $backDegree, task: $task)
            CardFront(width: width, height: height, degree: $frontDegree, task: $task)
        }.onTapGesture {
            flipCard ()
        }
    }
}

struct CardFront : View {
    let width : CGFloat
    let height : CGFloat
    @Binding var degree : Double
    @Binding var task: Task
    
    func calcResult() -> Double {
        var result: Double!
        
        switch task.operation {
        case .addition: result = task.operator1 + task.operator2
        case .substraction: result = task.operator1 - task.operator2
        case .mulitply: result = task.operator1 * task.operator2
        case .division: result = task.operator1 / task.operator2
        }
            return result
    }
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .fill(.white)
                .frame(width: width, height: height)
                .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 2, x: 0, y: 0)
            
                .overlay(
                         Text("\(calcResult(), specifier: "%.2f")"))
        }.rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: degree), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
    }
}

struct CardBack : View {
    let width : CGFloat
    let height : CGFloat
    @Binding var degree : Double
    @Binding var task: Task
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .fill(.white)
                .frame(width: width, height: height)
                .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 2, x: 0, y: 0)
            
                .overlay(
                    Text("\(String(task.operator1)) \(task.operation.rawValue) \(String(task.operator2))")
                )
            
        }.rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: degree), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
        
    }
}

struct Task {
    var operator1: Double
    var operator2: Double
    var operation: Operations
}

enum Operations: String, CaseIterable {
    case addition = "+"
    case division = "/"
    case mulitply = "x"
    case substraction = "-"
}
```

Here a gif of how it looks like in the simulator:

[image: Flip Card Animation]